# How to Fetch data when the array is inside Json object in angularjs?

Tags: arrays, angularjs, json

I have a API response DATA which is like below, there I'm trying to extract CONTACTS which I needed.

```
$scope.data = Object { ACCOUNT: "{"ACNO":"AC052","NAME":"madavi",…}", 
                       CONTACTS: Array[1], RETURN: "TRUE" }
```

After Extracting the CONTACTS from the json and i get

```
Array [ "{"CONTACTNAME":"Mr. sdhar","CONTA…"}", 
        "{"CONTACTNAME":"Ms. uma","CONTACTPH…"}" ]
```

I'm trying like this

```
  $scope.contactdetails = data.CONTACTS; 

  <div ng-repeat="contacts in contactdetails">              
      <a> {{ contact.CONTACTNAME  }} </a>
      <a> {{ contact.CONTACTEMAIL  }} </a>
      <a> {{ contact.CONTACTPHONE  }} </a> 
      <br>
  </div>
```

How can I get values in ng-repeat?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each element in your array seems to be in string form, so after assigning it run JSON.parse on it:

```
$scope.contactdetails   = data.CONTACTS; 

for(var x = 0; x < $scope.contactdetails.length; x++){
    $scope.contactdetails[x] = JSON.parse($scope.contactdetails[x]);
}
```